# How to change encoding for an unnamed buffer in VIM?

Tags: vim, character-encoding

Is it possible?

I only know how it can be done for a named buffer (file). It should be reopened with

`++enc=<encoding>` option. But an unnamed buffer cannot be reopened.

I executed `:set encoding=utf-8` but the text displayed in VIM was still unreadable. Only after I saved the buffer to a file, opened it and reopened it with `:e ++enc=utf-8` it could be read well. However I noticed that there was an error `[ILLEGAL BYTE in line 37]`. But I'm happy with that. The main thing is that the contents are readable.

There was no error when I ran `:set encoding=utf-8`, but nothing seemed to happen too.

VIM 7.4

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to re-open it - while in command mode, you can set the encoding to whatever you like with:

```
:set encoding=whatever
```

e.g.

```
:set encoding=utf-8
```

BTW, type `:help encoding-names` in `vim` for a list of supported encodings.

Comment: I've tried it, but there may be a difference between '++enc' and 'set encoding'. I'll update my question.

Comment: maybe put it in your ~/.vimrc so that utf-8 is the default encoding (i'm a little surprised it isn't aready the default...unless your .vimrc has decades worth of cruft like mine)

Comment: It is the default encoding. Because if I start vim and execute ':set encoding?' it shows me 'encoding=utf-8'. I don't know whether this is an intentional behaviour or not but '++enc' seems to be able to force encoding regardless whether there are some invalid characters there while 'set encoding' can't.

Answer (score 0):

The `'encoding'` option is about Vim's internal representation of text in *all* buffers. This should not be changed after Vim has started, and it doesn't (at least not directly) affect the encoding of a buffer!

You're looking for the [`:help 'fileencoding'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27fileencoding%27) option:

```
:setlocal fenc=...
```

To summarize: What kind of characters can be typed and represented within a new buffer is controlled by the `'encoding'` option. The "best" value for that is `utf-8`, as only that can represent *any* character (within Unicode). Now, if you've created an unnamed buffer and want to store it in a different coding, you use `'fileencoding'` to change it (e.g. to `ucs-2le`) for the first and subsequent writes. (`:w ++enc=...` also works, but only for that particular write!)

In contrast, for the *detection* of opened files, you'd rather configure the `'fileencodings'` option.